# How can I make Perl Rest (minutes)

Tags: perl

Currently, I make perl rest between functions using

```
for my $j (0 .. 99999999){}
```

This somehow makes it rest for about 30 seconds (+/-5)

Is there a way I can more "efficiently" make perl rest? I'm trying to have it rest for 270 seconds (about) (4.5 minutes). And adding more 9's to my current rest statement would make the script very unhappy...

Comment: it also significantly consumes your CPU

Answer (score 6):

[`sleep(4.5 * 60);`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html)

.............

Comment: `sleep()` is in seconds, Karthik.

Comment: @Karthik T, The "." are there to meet SO minimum character limit. I guess I should add to the answer instead, but there's really nothing else to add.

Comment: You might add that `sleep` is the proper way to stop execution in a script and not writing a giant `for` loop.  But this is just my opinion.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, I misunderstood, I assumed that indicated that the "..." disbelief that the OP would use a busy loop for this purpose. But perhaps I am being too snobbish..

Comment: @squiguy I'm trying to write a giant for loop... How would I do this if sleep does stop execution?

Comment: @squiguy, That's the question, not the answer. I don't see the point of repeating the question.